# Recreating Log File While Java Still Running

Tags: java, logging

So I'm currently running a Java application that will be running for a couple of days. It does a lot of logging. Unfortunately, I accidentally deleted the log file, so now, no more logs are being written. Is there a way to restart the logging "on the fly" without restarting the actual Java program? I tried re-creating the file with the exact same name, but it is not being written to. Any ideas? I am using `java.util.logging`.

Comment: Depends on how logging is implemented. Probably not from the sounds of it.

Comment: It really depends on the logging library you use but with log4j and similar I have seen that logs will not be written if the file is removed externally. Your best best is to restart the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can load java class in your application "on the fly", then try to use following method [LogManager.reset()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#reset()) or [LogManager.readConfiguration()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration()).